# Programmatically set default branch name for new Azure repositories

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos

With recent changes introduced in Azure repositories the default branch name will be changed to "main" instead of "master". However Microsoft provided a feature to set the default branch name for the repositories which will be created in the future.

[image]

This feature can be easily turn on/off using the web ui. But I need to toggle this feature programmatically (using REST API or CLI) While browsing through the REST API documentation I didn't find a way to achieve this. Is there a way to get this done?

Analyzing the backend API call I found this,
`https://dev.azure.com/{organization_name}/{project_id}/_api/_versioncontrol/UpdateRepositoryOption?__v=5&repositoryId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`
But unable to send the request via postman or curl.

Comment: Although it seems that you can't toggle that feature programmatically, you can always update any existing repository with the new default branch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT,
As a workaround when initializing the repository I check for the current branch and create a master branch if it's something else. Then after pushing it back to the remote I update the repo to set the default branch to master (using the cli)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not public API I think and even if you try to send you may not be able to overcome security checks. I tired and I got error message

> The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present. Ensure that cookies

[image]

You may create a feature request to make this avialble over REST API [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). But, for the moment you are forced to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Krzysztof Madej.

Test with the backend API to change the Repo Settings(New)/Options(Old), I get the same issue.

> The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not
> present. Ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

This is [a ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/121815/invoke-restmethod.html) with a similar problem.

The product group confirms that there is no workaround for this issue. It is indeed a security check.

When encountering this problem, it shows that this API cannot be called outside of a Azure Devops web page.

I am afraid that there is **no** API/CLI to achieve your requirement, you can only achieve it through the UI page for the time being.

Comment: I initialized an empty git repo with Default branch name for new repositories set to "main"
Then cloned it and initialized the repo with some files locally. When pushed back to the remote the branch name is still "master" 
Is it the normal behavior? Or will it change in the future?

Comment: Hi @ShehanWeerasooriya. Test with git command to clone and push the repo, it could work as expected. The branch name keeps showing as `main`. Could you please share some steps?  On the other hand, that's probably a separate question. I suggest you can create a new ticket. It will be more convenient to solve this issue.

Comment: As a workaround when initializing the repository I check for the current branch and create a master branch if it's something else. Then after pushing it back to the remote I update the repo to set the default branch to master (using the cli)